# timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d) not evaluated in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that calls another shell script. One of the parameters is the output filename which I want to prefix with a timestamp. So far I've been doing it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

bash resign "$(date +%Y%m%d)_UI_Touch_SU_test_$version.ipa"
```

This is working fine. The resulting filename is `20151029_UI_Touch_SU_test_21.6.5212.ipa`. However I want to customize the filename further and have a date variable:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d)
bash resign "$timestamp_UI_Touch_SU_test_$version.ipa"
```

This is not working. The resulting filename is `21.6.5212.ipa`. How do I set the date variable correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
bash resign "${timestamp}_UI_Touch_SU_test_${version}.ipa"
```

You need the `{}` to delimit the variable from the rest of the string.

Edit: Note, that `$version.ipa` also works without the curly braces, since the dot `.` is not a valid variable character in bash (in contrast the underscore `_` is). However, I think it is good practise to use the curly braces there as well.

Comment: I tried to add an explanation, please check if it is sufficient.